# How many environment variables does Windows 11 allow?

Tags: windows-11, environment-variables

I have quite many environment variables scattered both in User Variables and System variables, and I cannot add more variables, which leads me to a question: ***is there an upper limit on the number of environment variables?***

Comment: yes. Does that answer the question? There is also a restriction on the amount of characters (which is relevant in case of for example PATH) https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100203-00/?p=15083 Because of the environment block limit it is quite hard to calculate an actual max number of env vars but there is an upper limit.

Comment: It is of course a meaningless number because its not like it would make sense to make 100+ env vars with single char names and values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one limit for the totality of the
environment variables, which is 32767 bytes.
This is the size of the environment block, which is the block
containing the variables and which is passed to any process
from its parent.

The environment block contains the variables in a byte stream
that has the format of:

```
Var1=Value1\0
Var2=Value2\0
Var3=Value3\0
...
VarN=ValueN\0\0
```

If you have reached this limit of 32767 bytes, you will need
to either reduce your number of variables, or reduce their values
or even their names. Because every byte counts.

For more information, see the Microsoft article
[Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables).

Comment: The page you linked states that the 32767 byte limit is only for server 2002 and Windows XP and was removed in Vista and above: "Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: The maximum size of the environment block for the process is 32,767 characters. Starting with Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, there is no technical limitation on the size of the environment block."

Comment: @Mokubai: There is still a practical limit of 32767 bytes that's still built into some parts of the Windows software. I can't say exactly which Windows software is blocking the poster.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Gantendo, there is a limit on both the number of variables and teh total space for the environment block.  This is normal in programming, everything has to have a upper limit.

In your case, it is more likely that you have hit on the total environment block size.  The solution is to reduce the length of some variables.